# Issue with STD error fill

Tags: matlab

I have a (X,Y) dataset (see end of this message) and I want to plot with the std.error marked as shading. However, I have have problem when the std is 0. Here is a simple code is use for testing:

```
x = Data(:,1);
y = Data(:,2);
std = 0.3*y;
fill([x;flipud(x)],[y-std;flipud(y+std)],[.2 .9 .9],'linestyle','none');
line(x,y);
alpha(0.1);
```

The std is my std. error which is working fine here, but when I change this to 0 (0*y) it is looks strange (it should be equal the line). I am using Matlab 2015b.
[image]

My dataset is:

```
Data = [
  260.0000         0
  259.5000   -0.0166
  259.0000   -0.0487
  258.5000   -0.0445
  258.0000   -0.0437
  257.5000   -0.0638
  257.0000   -0.0583
  256.5000   -0.0880
  256.0000   -0.0961
  255.5000   -0.0706
  255.0000   -0.0863
  254.5000   -0.1051
  254.0000   -0.1140
  253.5000   -0.1329
  253.0000   -0.1307
  252.5000   -0.1433
  252.0000   -0.1625
  251.5000   -0.1366
  251.0000   -0.1359
  250.5000   -0.1413
  250.0000   -0.1438
  249.5000   -0.1538
  249.0000   -0.1352
  248.5000   -0.1844
  248.0000   -0.2098
  247.5000   -0.2066
  247.0000   -0.2031
  246.5000   -0.2036
  246.0000   -0.2479
  245.5000   -0.2791
  245.0000   -0.3187
  244.5000   -0.3629
  244.0000   -0.4218
  243.5000   -0.5147
  200.0000    2.5618
  199.5000    3.9747
  199.0000    5.4836
  198.5000    7.0462
  198.0000    8.4347
  197.5000    9.7647
  197.0000   11.1262
  196.5000   12.2604
  196.0000   13.3529
  195.5000   14.4072
  195.0000   15.3222
  194.5000   16.1851
  194.0000   16.9095
  193.5000   17.4813
  193.0000   17.8846
  192.5000   18.1166
  192.0000   18.3644
  191.5000   18.5597
  191.0000   18.5822
  190.5000   18.5643
  190.0000   18.3095
  189.5000   17.9620
  189.0000   17.6198
  188.5000   17.1708
  188.0000   16.8142
  187.5000   16.4826
  187.0000   16.1231
  186.5000   15.1229
  186.0000   14.6209
  185.5000   13.4553
  185.0000   12.5914
  184.5000   10.4794
  184.0000    8.5036
  183.5000    6.4980
  183.0000    4.7882
  182.5000    3.7990
  182.0000    3.4504
  181.5000    0.5280
  181.0000   -0.9536
  180.5000   -3.2450
  180.0000   -4.9457]
```

If I use a smaller dataset (Data = [1 0; 2 5; 3 3; 4 2]) i get another strange plot with std=0 and fill([x;flipud(x)],[y-std;flipud(y+std)],[.2 .9 .9],'linestyle','none');:
[image]

Comment: FWIW, not reproducible in R2017b. Unrelated, you also shouldn't be shadowing [`std`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/std.html).

Comment: What do you mean by FWIW?

Comment: [For what it's worth](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/fwiw)

Comment: Ok thanks. So my code is not working in 2017?

Comment: "not reproducible" means the example does not reproduce the issue. Ergo, it provides the desired result.

Comment: Haha ok. Sorry for being a complete novice. So it seams R2015b is the problem.

Comment: Maybe. Or you're encountering an unrelated issue and the example code functions fine in R2015b.

Comment: Have you tried clearing all variables and rerunning the program? (`clear all`)

Comment: @flawr I did a clear all and tried the same code with the same result. I also tried a clear all and fill([x;flipud(x)],[y-0;flipud(y+0)],[.2 .9 .9],'linestyle','none') and still get the same strange plot.

Comment: What if you use less points? (`Data = [1 0; 2 5; 3 3; 4 2]`?)

Comment: Same strange issue when I use std=0 with your dataset: that is with fill([x;flipud(x)],[y-0;flipud(y+0)],[.2 .9 .9],'linestyle','none')

Comment: @flawr. I have included the plot in end of the original question above.

Comment: Seems like a bug to me - did you try to play with eps as in `std = (0*y)+eps` ?

Comment: @marsei. When I use std = (0*y)+eps I get a completely empty plot when using: fill([x;flipud(x)],[y-std;flipud(y+std)],[.2 .9.9],'linestyle','none'); and if I follow by line(x,y); I get the plot. It might be a solution.So if i have std=0.3*y should I still use std=0.3*y+eps?

Comment: `eps` adds nothing to the value (at least not in the range of what you are interested in), so you can be safe in using it wherever you want ([eps](https://fr.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/eps.html)).

Comment: So it seems when you actually plot a zero-area polygon, then the convex hull is plotted.

Comment: GREAT! Thanks a lot Marsei

Comment: Maybe it's a bug in plotting a polygon with overlapping vertices. I don't think it's plotting the convex hull on purpose, but it might delete vertices that are overlapping earlier vertices. I have seen similar results in the past.